# How to insert a Sqlite database file to Android and read it using Kotlin?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin

I am creating an Android app that reads data from multiple databases and the app must work offline. I saw lots of tutorials but they are in Java and I don't know how to use them in Kotlin since the app I am creating is currently in Kotlin. Can anyone help me to either create on in Kotlin or guide me to use the methods used in Java for my Kotlin app.

Comment: try to paste the java code into AS it automatically convert it to kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I use Android's [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) to access SQLite database

You can 100% kotlin code using [KAPT](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html), or give it in Java and not need KAPT, works ok in kotlin code calling the DAO objects in Java.

You say multiple databases ? Please explain that.
Is multiple tables in database instead ?

Comment: i have multiple database files. Is it better to  merge the two? I use the first database as a lookup to the other database that has 4 tables.

Comment: the problem is,  I am a complete noob at Android and I basically don't know what to do when kotlin and java is mixed up.

Comment: Another approach to sqlite in kotlin : https://antonioleiva.com/databases-anko-kotlin/